# How to hide element when finishing scrolling to some specific point without having page moved, it should stay to scrolled area

Tags: jquery, scroll, hide

Here is the [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/1d6u315L/1/) with my question.

I want to create scroll in the way that when I will finish scrollling to .bottom and then wanted to hide .top.

Here is the peice of code

```
jQuery('.arrow img').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery(".bottom").offset().top
            }, 3000);
          jQuery('.top').hide();
    });
```

Comment: You need to put `jQuery('.top').hide()` into the animates `.done()` function, then it is executed after the animation is done.

Comment: can you type the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.Here is the code

```
jQuery('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".homeFirstSection").offset().top
            }, 2000,function(){
                    $('#video-container').hide(1, function(){
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                    scrollTop: $(".homeFirstSection").offset().top
                            }, 1);
                    });
            });
```

Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.arrow img').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery(".bottom").offset().top
        }, 3000, function(){jQuery('.top').hide();});
});
```

should work, but didn't test due to time issues

Comment: yes it works but now another thing appeared, when it hides div the red elemt moved to bottom.How to create that it will remain in the position that is scrolled to?

Comment: That is because the page gets smaller, try wwith the bottom height at 1500px

Comment: how can I create it dynamically cause I didnt know in the future what height my content will have

Comment: did you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You need to put more information about what exactly you try to archive in your question then. The way it is now, you scroll down to were bottom starts and when you hide the top, the scroll offset remains and you no longer at at the start of bottom. I do not know if that is the desired effect

Comment: Disired effect is when scrolling to red part do not allow user to go up

Comment: and after scroling and hidign the black part do not have movement

Comment: Please edit as much as possible into your question, so we don't just chat it down here in the comments, and so other users can see it better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86763/discussion-between-anahit-dev-and-user3154108).